# How would you truncate the result of summing a group of numbers to exactly 8 decimal places?

Tags: clojure

For my cryptocurrency trading program, I want to truncate all floating point numbers to exactly 8 places. How would I do this in Clojure?

Here is a related code sample:

```
(with-precision 8 :rounding DOWN
  (bigdec 
   (+ 0.2
      0.0109     ; 1/1
      0.0285     ; 1/2
      0.02858    ; 1/3
      0.01963    ; 1/4
      0.00392977 ; 1/5
      0.00956410 ; 1/6
      0.02322879 ; 1/7
      0.01547502 ; 1/8
      0.01616702 ; 1/9
      0.01463114 ; 1/10
      0.00843843 ; 1/11
      0.01162393 ; 1/12
      )))
```

It currently returns `0.39066819999999997` but I would like it to return `0.39066819`.

Answer (score 9):

I would use [`with-precision`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-precision) which allows you to specify the precision and rounding mode for your math operations with `BigDecimal` numbers - and you should use them instead of floating point numbers for handling currency amounts. Notice that `M` in the number literal indicates it's a `BigDecimal` value. You can coerce your numbers to `BigDecimal` with [`bigdec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bigdec). If you would like to literally truncate the result you need to use `DOWN` rounding mode.

```
(with-precision 3 :rounding DOWN
  (+ (bigdec 0.1111111111) 0.22222222M))
;; => 0.333M
```

Make sure that your operations are done on `BigDecimal`s as the conversion to `bigdec` is not impacted by `with-precision`:

```
(with-precision 3 :rounding DOWN
  (bigdec 0.11111111))
;; => 0.11111111M

(with-precision 3 :rounding DOWN
  (* 1M (bigdec 0.11111111)))
;; => 0.111M
```

If you would like to modify the `BigDecimal` value directly you need to use Java interop (either via `BigDecimal` constructor accepting properly configured `MathContext` or by calling `.round` instance method).

Comment: The "M" [represents a big decimal number by the way](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-precision#example-542692cbc026201cdc326bb1).

Comment: It does not truncate the number - the result still has more than 8 decimal places:

Comment: Your math operation must be done on the bigdec numbers, not on doubles that are converted to bigdec in the last step.